# Oracle: how to avoid FRA become full?

Tags: oracle

My Oracle instance won't start

```
Total System Global Area|1608409464|bytes
Fixed Size              |  10043768|bytes
Variable Size           |1107296256|bytes
Database Buffers        | 486539264|bytes
Redo Buffers            |   4530176|bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 1341
Session ID: 4 Serial number: 23966
```

I already know the problem.. is the FRA full

```
du -sh /opt/oracle/oraflash
30G /opt/oracle/oraflash
```

I already know how to solve this

```
SQL> startup mount;
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area|1608409464|bytes
Fixed Size              |  10043768|bytes
Variable Size           |1107296256|bytes
Database Buffers        | 486539264|bytes
Redo Buffers            |   4530176|bytes
SQL>
```

Then I run rman

```
RMAN> crosscheck archivelog all;
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO APPLIED ON ALL STANDBY;
delete noprompt archivelog all;
```

Finally I can run oracle

```
sqlplus / as sysdba

shutdown immediate
startup
```

My question is: how to configure Oracle to avoid the FRA become full so fast without extend the FRA size? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*how to configure Oracle to avoid the FRA become full so fast*

The database just doesn't generate logs by itself for fun...It is *workload* on the database the generates logs, so you need to see where your workload is coming from.

Check out AWR reports, v$sesstat, v$segstats, v$sql et al to see which sessions, apps and SQL statements are doing lots of work and look at seeing if any of that is redundant or can be improved.

Deleting archives just because they are applied on the standby is also a risky proposition (I'm hoping you've backed them up as well or you're retaining them on the standby node?).

Comment: Thanks for answer, a lot of people said Oracle can delete automatically archives when the FRA become full, but seem not my case.

Comment: The database can indeed delete files automatically, but only if they have satisfied all requirements for those files, eg, if the policy is (say) "backed up twice" and you have not done so, then we wont delete it